# How can I extract data from spinners to another layout?

Tags: android, database, android-intent, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I need help with my application. I put some spinners in one layout, and I need to retrieve the text in the SelectedItems to put them in another layout, maybe in a TextView.

**I used:**

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selecTipoCP = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    String TipoCP = selecTipoCP;

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(CPOrder.this,Finalizar.class);
    intent1.putExtra("var_tipoCP", TipoCP);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

and it functions, but the activity starts immediately. I want to enter this layout, and I want to start the activity only when I press a button.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134043/2553431)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to separate your code to add the functionality you want something like this.

Create an event for your button.

```
 @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {


                      addCustomListenerOnSpinner();
         }




     private void addCustomListenerOnSpinner(){

         yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {

            String value=String.valueOf(yourSpinner.getSelectedItem());
             Intent intent1 = new Intent(CPOrder.this,Finalizar.class);
             intent1.putExtra("var_tipoCP", value);
             startActivity(intent1);
          }
         });

     }
```

**Other way ...**

```
    @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

                  //only we pass the data
                  addCustomListenerOnSpinner(parent,position);
     }




 private void addCustomListenerOnSpinner(final AdapterView<?> parent,final int position){

     yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

         String selecTipoCP =parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
         Intent intent1 = new Intent(CPOrder.this,Finalizar.class);
         intent1.putExtra("var_tipoCP", selecTipoCP);
         startActivity(intent1);
      }
     });

 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help